# Color rgb initializer not working as background in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to set a button's background color to some custom rgb value. I create the button as follows:

```
Button(action: {
    print("tapped")
}) {
    Text("Let's go")
}
    .background(Color.black)
```

This works fine, and the button's background is, in fact, black. However, when initializing the background color like this, it does not work and there's just no background color at all:

```
.background(Color(red: 242, green: 242, blue: 242))
```

Why is that?

Comment: FWIW, that exact code does make the button's background black in my test (as run on the iPad Pro simulator).

Comment: It's really weird: sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. The color I wanted was `242, 242, 242`. When changing each value from `0` to `242`, it *did* change the color in the preview for the red and green values, but once I also changed the blue value, it turned white again.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

It looks like it is asking for the colors in percentages, I was able to get it to work doing this

```
Color(red: 242 / 255, green: 242 / 255, blue: 242 / 255)
```

Comment: It looks like the values that need to be passed in are actually [sRGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB).

Answer (score 15):

The `Color` expects 3 `Double` values from `0.0` to `1.0` for each tone. If you pass this...

WRONG:

```
.background(Color(red: 242, green: 242, blue: 242))
```

It is converted to WHITE since all values are bigger than 1.

To fix this you could divide each value by `255` and get your hex conversion (as the 1 Answer)

CORRECT:

```
Color(red: 242 / 255, green: 242 / 255, blue: 242 / 255)
```